# Best way to categorize a list

Tags: java, collections

I have an Order object

```
public class Order{
  private Date orderDate;
  //other fields + getters & setters
}
```

And a List of Orders (**List< Orders>**). Now I want to group this list of orders based on similar orderDate (similar in here means, same year, month and day) and produce a map like this:

```
Map<Date, List<Order>> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
```

How to do this in Java 8+ ?

> Take note we might have similar date but different timestamp which means we
>   want to based it on "year, month, day"

Comment: Define "similar"

Comment: @QBrute dates with same year, month, day

Comment: @michalk does not work if we have different hours, min, second for the day

Comment: Yep, right. Btw are you forced to use deprectated classes form `java.util`? There is `java.time` package which has classes like `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` which should be used.

Comment: @michalk Please post your solution, whatever it is

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

As the key to your  `Map< LocalDate , List< Order> >`:

```
    order
    .getDate()                                  // Accessor method to retrieve your `java.util.Date` object.
    .toInstant()                                // Convert from terrible legacy class `Date` to modern `java.time.Instant` class. Both represent a moment in UTC.
    .atZone(                                    // Adjust from UTC to the time zone used by your business.
            ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) 
    )                                           // Remember: For any given moment, the date varies around globe by time zone, “tomorrow” in Tokyo while “yesterday” in Montréal. 
    .toLocalDate()                              // Extract the date-only portion, without time-of-day, without time zone, to use as the key in our map.
```

## Keep your `Date` member

If you cannot change the type of your `orderDate` member variable from the terrible `java.util.Date` class, then do the business logic in *java.time*. Convert to/from `Date` using the new methods added to the old classes.

### Do *not* use `LocalDateTime`

Using *java.time* has been discussed in other Answers, but those use the wrong class: [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). That is exactly the wrong class to use as it does *not* represent a moment. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe. The class holds a date and a time-of-day but has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So if a `LocalDateTime` object holds 12 PM on the 23rd of January this year, we have no idea if that was meant to be noon in Tokyo, noon in Kolkata, noon in Paris, or noon in Montréal — all very different moments, several hours apart.

To represent a moment, use one of these:

- `Instant`
  A moment in UTC
- `OffsetDateTime`
  A moment with an offset-from-UTC, some number of hours-minutes-seconds
- `ZonedDateTime`
  A moment as seen through the offset used by the people of a particular region, that time zone having a name in `Continent/Region` format

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### `Date` ➙ `Instant`

The replacement for `java.util.Date` is `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC, though `Instant` has a finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) versus milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = orderDate.toInstant() ;
```

### Time zone

Adjust from UTC to your desired time zone. Do you want to perceive the date as seen in [Barstow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barstow,_California), California? Use `America/Los_Angeles` time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. This `ZonedDateTime` represents the same moment, the same point on the timeline, as the `Instant`, but uses a different wall-clock time.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Note that the *java.time* classes [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design, using [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So you can define this `ZoneId` once and keep it around for reuse, even across threads.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock-time.
```

### `LocalDate`

Extract the date-only portion, without the time-of-day and without the time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // The date as seen for this moment in Barstow, California.
```

Use the `LocalDate` as the key to your `Map< LocalDate , List< Order> >`.

## Change your `Date` member to `Instant`

> How to do this in Java 8+ ?

Best to migrate your code from the terrible legacy date-time classes to the modern *java.time* classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on the old classes when they adopted JSR 310. So should you — they really are that bad.

Generally best on the backend to work, think, store, and exchange date-time values in UTC. Apply a time zone only for (a) presentation to the user, (b) if required by the business logic.

```
public class Order{
  private Instant whenOrdered ;
  //other fields + getters & setters
}
```

Apply the same time-zone-adjustment logic seen above to get a `LocalDate` as the key to your `Map< LocalDate , List< Order > >`.

Display the `Instant` to the user in whatever time zone they prefer. Let *java.time* [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) the display text.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "fr" , "TN" ) ;      // French in Tunisia.
ZoneId userZone = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault() to get the JVM’s current default time zone (appropriate to a client machine, but not a server machine). 
String outputForDisplay = 
    order
    .whenOrdered
    .atZone( userZone )                          // Adjust from UTC to time zone, going from `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime`. 
    .format(                                     // Generate text representing the value inside our `ZonedDateTime` object.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG )  // Let java.time automatically localize, rather than hard-code a formatting pattern.
    ) 
;
```

If you only care about the date, not the time-of-day, and you don't care about the fuzziness of determining the date across time zones (you are in a small local business), use `LocalDate`.

```
public class Order{
  private LocalDate dateOrdered ;
  //other fields + getters & setters
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: the correct and right answer with incredible professionalism. I did learn something in this answer. But sometimes a fast and easy fix is "good enough", since this code could be used in big software, which ultimately builds on util.date and changing everything would just cost too much time and money.
If anyone has the same problem in a small project, go this way, not the easy and fast fix

Answer (score 3):

As `Date` class is deprecated and holds actual date and time, you could use `LocalDateTime` as your field in `Order` class. Then you could group your orders by `LocalDate` taken from `LocalDateTime` :

```
List<Order> list = new LinkedList<>();

Map<LocalDate, List<Order>> collect = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getOrderDate().toLocalDate()));
```

[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) holds year, month and day without time.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this one has two problems, 1) I don't want to use LocalDate for my key 2) that toLocalDate is for java.sql.Date not java.util.Date

Comment: `toLocalDate` is a method of `LocalDateTime` class here.

Comment: @Mehdi If you need finer granularity than `LocalDate` for your keys, consider `Instant`. On Java 8+ never use `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method that returns the 'similarity' of the Orders, e.g.:

```java
public class Order{
  private Date orderDate;
  //other fields + getters & setters
  public String getStringDate(){
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
     return dateFormat.format(this.orderDate);
  }
}
```

and then grouping on it:

```java
Map<String, List<Order>> ordersWithSimilarOrderDate = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getStringDate));
```

Comment: Theee terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `Date`, you can still convert it to `LocalDate` by providing the timezone information.

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Order>> collect =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order -> 
        order.getOrderDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really support the point of doing everything with streams, but you can do it
with a hard convertion way.

```java
 List<Order> orders = ... your list ...
 Map<Date, List<Order>> orderMap = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(order->{
      //Converting from Date to Instant
      Instant dateInstant = order.getOrderDate().toInstant();
      //Converting Instant to LocalDateTime and setting it to the start of the day
      LocalDateTime dateTime = dateInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
      //Converting it back to an instant
      Instant startOfDayInstant = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
      //Returning the util date
      return Date.from(startOfDayInstant);
    }));
```

This is under the circumstance that you *need* util date. Otherwise I support the answer from michalk

Comment: your answer deserved to be chosen if it was posted faster

Comment: @Mehdi You can switch your acceptance to another Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque I know but it's not ethical. There's always a next time man

Comment: @Mehdi Stack Overflow is not a game of time. Its founders intended it to be more like Wikipedia, a repository of knowledge to guide posterity, and less like a chat room or forum. You are welcome to change your acceptance years later if an Answer appears that better fits the Question.